# Error Image display from python/flask backend to react app.js frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to send a generated image from a flask API to my React frontend. The image is saved in flask-server/src/bpmn.jpeg

Currently i am not displaying the image but just an epty container.

In flask I have:

```
@app.route('/image/bpmn.jpeg')
def get_image():
    return send_from_directory('/flask-server/src', 'bpmn.jpeg')
```

And the app.js is this:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/submit', { data: input });
      // Assuming the server's response includes a key 'imageUrl' with the value '/image/bpmn.jpeg'
      setImageUrl(`http://localhost:5000${result.data.imageUrl}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending data:', error);
    }
  };
```

I do not know why it does not display it correcetly. Help would be much apprecaited.

Comment: What did you do to debug this? What do you see in devtools of your browser?